# Get files on remote copy but not local

Tags: rsync, file-comparison

I have a folder.

I have one copy of this folder locally and one on a server. I edited my local folder as I wanted and then [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) it to the server.

Is there any way of comparing those two copies, local and remote, and get back a list of files that are on the remote one and not the local one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following rsync command executed on the local machine lists the files that exist on the remote host but not the local host.

```
rsync -av --dry-run --delete somedir/ user@remote:~/somedir/
```

The `--dry-run` switch only lists the files, without actually doing something, the `--delete` switch in combination with `-v` (verbose) lists the files that would be deleted because they exist on the remote host, but not the local host, which is want you want.

Answer (score 2):

[Unison File Synchronizer](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) does exactly that using the rsync algorithm for the heavy lifting. I use it daily.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have ssh keys to do your rsync, you could issue a remote ssh command and list the files in the dir, then diff it with a copy from your local dir.

```
ssh user@remote.com ls -1 ~/foo > /tmp/remote.txt && ls -1 ~/foo > /tmp/local.txt && diff /tmp/remote.txt /tmp/local.txt
```

Extra credit, pipe the output of diff to [colordiff](http://www.colordiff.org/) for prettiness.